# Instantiate a DrawRect View From ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I apologize if this may be a simple question.  I am fairly new to using the draw rect and i want to call it from my ViewDidLoad in my view controller when the draw rect is in a view subclass.  All I have to do it so far is this but it doesn't do anything.  What do i need to add?  Thank you

```
circleView = [[CircleView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:circleView];
[circleView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Here is the code in my circle view

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"worked");
    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 255, 0.1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(contextRef, 0, 0, 255, 0.5);

    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(contextRef, CGRectMake(100, 100, 25, 25));

}
```

Thats all I have.  I know might need to init with frame but i dont know how to choose the draw rect.

Comment: When you debug it, is `drawRect:` called? What is its `frame`? What else can you tell about it?

Comment: What results would you expect? And please show some code in your `CircleView`

Comment: just updated, Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to call `[circleView setNeedsDisplay];` explicitly in your `-viewDidLoad`, for `UIView` will automatically invoke its `-drawRect:` when it is displaying first time.
Your `circleView` doesn't show because its `frame` is {0, 0; 0, 0}. You probably need to give it a meaningful `frame`, like this:

```
circleView = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
```

or set its `frame` property:

```
circleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
```